# How can I automate data extraction in this website? (can't see query options, if any)

Tags: r, bash, web-scraping, extract

I want to extract election results from [this website](http://www.servelelecciones.cl/) (currently all data is at zero because voting is ongoing). In the menu you can select the data you want (I need "En Chile" -> "División Geográfica" -> "Comunas"). This is the voting results for each municipality ("comuna"). When you select the desired "comuna", then you can click the excel file and results are downloaded.

The "problem" is that no url is shown along the process. I cannot see the url link to the particular "comuna" I need. I was hoping to get a specific link so then I can automate using `wget` with the name of each municipality. Instead, the data seems to be masked. I know you can extract JSON data, perhaps using the properties shown in the website's HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selComunas" ng-model="comuSelected"
    ng-options="item.d for item in comunas" name="comunas"
    ng-show="(vistaVertical==='G' || vistaVertical==='E') && subMenu === null"
    ng-change="updateComuna()">
    <option value="">Comunas...</option>
</select>
```

But where to make the call? No idea. Also, I see no link to the excel file in the HTML. Stuff seems to be masked inside "ng" elements, which seems to be AngularJS, as far as I can read online. No idea how to proceed. As you can see, I'm noob on this. Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: I mean computer language? Python, R, bash...?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Ah, I see. Bash and R. Will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open chrome dev tools and look for something useful there while clicking on the UI

http://www.servelelecciones.cl/data/elecciones_constitucion/filters/comunas/all.json

This link returns all `communas` with their ids

```
[{"c":2564,"d":"ALGARROBO"},{"c":2801,"d":"ALHUE"},{"c":2674,"d":"ALTO BIOBIO"},...
```

Next thing, when we select value from dropdown, we get another link in network tab. Number in the end matches, isn't it?

http://www.servelelecciones.cl/data/elecciones_constitucion/computo/comunas/2570.json

```
      "d":"Integer",
      "e":"Integer",
      "f":"Integer",
      "sd":null
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "a":"Apruebo",
         "b":null,
         "c":"0",
         "d":"0,00%",
         "e":null,
         "f":"",
         "sd":null
      },
      {
         "a":"Rechazo",
         "b":null,
         "c":"0",
         "d":"0,00%",
         "e":null,
         "f":"",
         "sd":null
      }
```

From this point you can process JSON directly by whatever programming language you use

Comment: Oh, that is amazing. I'm not used to dev tools. I always go fo the source code but I should learn more about it. Thanks. That is precisely what I needed! I can take over from here.